# How to make AUTO_INCREMENT on Android SQLite database?

Tags: android, sqlite

Hey I want to create a database with an AUTO_INCREMENT column. But I don't know how to parse the value in the method insert. I just don't know what to parse to an AUTO_INCREMENT argument, and I parsed 1 where should be auto_increment, but I know its not that I should parse.

Here is the **CallDatHelper.java** class where I declare the method insert, and the method that creates the database.

```
package com.psyhclo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CallDataHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "calls.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "contact_data";

private Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public CallDataHelper(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context);
    this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public boolean insert(Integer cId, String cName, String numType,
        String cNum, String dur, String date, String currTime) {
    this.db.execSQL("insert into "
            + TABLE_NAME
            + "(id, contact_id, contact_name, number_type, contact_number, duration, date, current_time, cont) "
            + "values( ? ," + cId + ", " + cName + ", " + numType + ", "
            + cNum + ", " + dur + ", " + date + ", " + currTime + ", ? )");
    return true;        
}

public void atualiza(String word) {
    this.db.execSQL("UPDATE words SET cont = cont + 1 WHERE (word= ?)",
            new String[] { word });
}

public void deleteAll() {
    this.db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
}

public boolean select(String wrd) {

    String word;
    Cursor cursor = this.db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "word" },
            "word like ?", new String[] { wrd }, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            word = cursor.getString(0);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public List<String> selectAll() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor = this.db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "word" },
            null, null, null, null, "cont desc");
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            list.add(cursor.getString(0).toUpperCase());
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return list;
}

private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    OpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "
                + TABLE_NAME
                + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, contact_id INTEGER, contact_name VARCHAR(50), number_type VARCHAR(50), contact_number VARCHAR(50), duration TIME, date DATE, current_time TIME, cont INTEGER)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w("RatedCalls Database",
                "Upgrading database, this will drop tables and recreate.");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
}
```

And here is where I call the **insert** method parsing the data I want to insert.

```
this.dh.insert(1 , 1, contactName, numType, contactNumber,
                    duration, callDate, currTime);
```

Comment: Let me make a security remark here: manually constructing SQL queries like this is a sure recipe to get hacked very hard. If an attacker gets to decide the value of any of those arguments the query can be modified completely. See more information here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't have to parse anything. If the column was created as `AUTOINCREMENT`, just pass the other values:

```
db.execSQL("insert into "
        + TABLE_NAME
        + "(contact_id, contact_name, number_type, contact_number, duration, date, current_time, cont) "
        + "values( "+ cId + ", " + cName + ", " + numType + ", "
        + cNum + ", " + dur + ", " + date + ", " + currTime + ", ? )");
```

By the way, it's always recommended to insert data using the Android's `insert` method:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("contact_id", cId);
values.put("contact_name", cName);
// etc.
db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```

Comment: but how to implement this in another class? Better, how to call this method on the other class, that just reference it and parse the right arguments?

Comment: Well... you already have a method for that, just use it... what's the problem?

Comment: I say, the db.insert method must be called on the Activity right? But for call this method I need to iniciate the object db, which is a SQLiteDatabase object. But how to iniciate it on the activity? I mean, private SQLiteDatabase db = 'what???'.

Comment: You already have a `CallDataHelper` class, don't you? Just do: `CallDataHelper blah = new CallDataHelper(YourActivity.this); blah.insert(blah blah);`

Answer (score 23):

You don't have to specifically write `AUTO_INCREMENT` as in MYSQL.

Just have to define the primary key Field as `_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`.

It will not work, if have define the Primary key field with `INT` when creating the table. It Should be `INTEGER` and thats it.

When you don't pass any value for the primary key filed when inserting records, it will automatically increase the value to be a unique value( same way `MYSQL` `AUTO_INCREMENT` works )

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a mention of MySQL anywhere in the question.

Comment: I think JibW is just making a comparison with MySQL to explain things better.

Comment: Haha, that was my problem. I declared it as INT ;) Thanks.

Comment: Just to add a note on why **AUTO_INCREMENT** statement should be avoided . `The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is usually not needed.` https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html.
Using **INTEGER PRIMARY KEY** is suffice.

Comment: **AUTOINCREMENT** should be use if you want to avoid the re-use of `ROWIDs` over the life time of database. `i.e the purpose of AUTOINCREMENT is to prevent the reuse of ROWIDs from previously deleted rows.`

Answer (score 1):

```
this.db.insert(NULL , 1, contactName, numType, contactNumber,
                    duration, callDate, currTime);
```

Comment: There's no `NULL` keyword in Java.

Answer (score 1):

```
final static String Database_name="empDb.db";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, Database_name, null, 1);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table emp_tbl (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT,salary TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_emp");
}
```

Get More Info 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8-Z85oPNmQ

Blog: https://itmulc.blogspot.com/2016/08/android-sqlite-database-with-complete.html

Answer (score -1):

```
this.db.insert(null , 1, contactName, numType, contactNumber,
                duration, callDate, currTime);
```

use java `null` instead of SQL `NULL`

Comment: Hi. This has nothing to do with the question, you seem to be correcting a quite old and irrelevant answer; this should be a comment on it.