# Error when using Android SQLiteDatabase insert() method

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to use a method insert from SQLiteDatabase in my Activity. But I'm having this error:

> 12-08 13:28:24.497: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20051): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   12-08 13:28:24.497: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20051):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)
>   12-08 13:28:24.497: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20051):     at com.psyhclo.RatedCalls.onCreate(RatedCalls.java:42)

The error is in this line:

> this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();

here is the code for the activity named **RatedCalls.java**:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import com.psyhclo.R;
import com.psyhclo.CallDataHelper.OpenHelper;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;

public class RatedCalls extends ListActivity {

private Context context;
private static TextView txtView;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private CallDataHelper dh = null;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context);


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC ");

    dh = new CallDataHelper(this);  
    db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    int numberColumnId = cursor
            .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int durationId = cursor
            .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    int contactNameId = cursor
            .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
    int dateId = cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int numTypeId = cursor
            .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE);
    Date dt = new Date();
    int hours = dt.getHours();
    int minutes = dt.getMinutes();
    int seconds = dt.getSeconds();
    String currTime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

    ArrayList<String> callList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            String contactNumber = cursor.getString(numberColumnId);
            String contactName = cursor.getString(contactNameId);
            String duration = cursor.getString(durationId);
            String callDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(dateId);
            String numType = cursor.getString(numTypeId);

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put("contact_id", 1);
            values.put("contact_name", contactName);
            values.put("number_type", numType);
            values.put("contact_number", contactNumber);
            values.put("duration", duration);
            values.put("date", callDate);
            values.put("current_time", currTime);
            values.put("cont", 1);

            this.db.insert(CallDataHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

            this.dh.insert(1, contactName, numType, contactNumber,
                    duration, callDate, currTime);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inserted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            callList.add("Contact Number: " + contactNumber
                    + "\nContact Name: " + contactName + "\nDuration: "
                    + duration + "\nDate: " + callDate);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listitem,
            callList));
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
    }
```

And here is the Datahelper class named **CallDataHelper.java** where the OpenHelper class is declared as a subclass.

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CallDataHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "calls.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
protected static final String TABLE_NAME = "contact_data";

private Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public CallDataHelper(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context);
    this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public boolean insert(Integer cId, String cName, String numType,
        String cNum, String dur, String date, String currTime) {
    this.db.execSQL("insert into "
            + TABLE_NAME
            + " (contact_id, contact_name, number_type, contact_number, duration, date, current_time, cont) "
            + " values( " + cId + ", " + cName + ", " + numType + ", "
            + cNum + ", " + dur + ", " + date + ", " + currTime + ", 1)");
    return true;        
}   

public void update(String word) {
    this.db.execSQL("UPDATE words SET cont = cont + 1 WHERE (word= ?)",
            new String[] { word });
}

public void deleteAll() {
    this.db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
}

public boolean select(String wrd) {

    String word;
    Cursor cursor = this.db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "word" },
            "word like ?", new String[] { wrd }, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            word = cursor.getString(0);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public List<String> selectAll() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor = this.db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "word" },
            null, null, null, null, "cont desc");
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            list.add(cursor.getString(0).toUpperCase());
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return list;
}

public static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    OpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "
                + TABLE_NAME
                + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, contact_id INTEGER, contact_name VARCHAR(50), number_type VARCHAR(50), contact_number VARCHAR(50), duration TIME, date DATE, current_time TIME, cont INTEGER)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w("RatedCalls Database",
                "Upgrading database, this will drop tables and recreate.");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is on this post!

[How to make AUTO_INCREMENT on Android SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388459/how-to-make-auto-increment-on-android-sqlite-database/4388551#4388551)

Answer (score 0):

You're instantiating `openHelper` when the activity is created, and at that point, `context` is null.

```
private Context context;

OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context);

db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Maybe you meant to do?

```
dh = new CallDataHelper(this);  
db = dh.getWritableDatabase();
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `OpenHelper` class.
You have declare it as a `static` class and you have a constructor in it.

Remove the `static` to be able to instantiate the `OpenHelper` class

Also you have initialize `openHelper` with

```
OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context);
```

outside any method, so you dont have any reference to the current object with `this`.

Try :

```
OpenHelper openHelper;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    openHelper = new OpenHelper(this);
```

Comment: Its now Working. I have some doubts. Where should I intialize openHelper OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context);?? And this onCreate method is the Activity method?

Comment: Yes this `onCreate` method is in your Activity