# Android database doesn't add/read row's

Tags: android, database, sqlite, rows

I just want to create simple database, one table with two columns: id, which will be auto incremented and data, so with my target data to store. I created this code, which doesn't return any error but also don't add any data:

```
database = openOrCreateDatabase ("alldata", 0, null);
    try{
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE cars(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,data INTEGER);");
    }
    catch(SQLException e){

    }

    //database.execSQL("INSERT INTO cars(data) values(0);");
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO cars(data) values(1);");
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO cars(data) values(2);");
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO cars(data) values(3);");
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO cars(data) values(4);");
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO cars(data) values(5);");

    String[] data={"_id","data"};
    Cursor c=database.query(false, "cars", data, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    int i=0;
    if(c.getCount()>0){
        c.moveToFirst();
        readed[i]=c.getInt(0);
        readed[i+1]=c.getInt(1);
        i+=2;
    }
```

And when i try to read the "readed" table it only shows two zeros 00:

```
            for(int i=0;i<readed.length;i++){
                if(readed[i] != null)
                    draw_number((int) readed[i],canvas,(float)(0.9*width-i*0.05*width),(float)(0.8*height));
            }
```

Draw number is my methos which is drawing a number on surfaceview, there is nothing wrong with this one. But unfortunetly I do not know, where is a problem with database. As far as i know I did everything ok and it should return:
0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 (because earlier I added one 0 to data column.)
But it only returns 0 0
Any ideas?

Comment: Shame on you. Voting down and closing would not be enough (so I will not do either). How can you even have the nerve of saying that "no error messages are displayed", since your own code disables reporting exceptions? It's like closing your eyes and whining that you cannot see the way.

Comment: But I'm catching this exception because code should create table ONE time. When the table is created I shouldn't and I cannot create the same table again. But it is created in database one time. Then I want to add rows to this table (which is already created in the past).

Comment: Ok, I know what's the problem. I was reading only first line... Instead of:

        if(c.getCount()>0){
            c.moveToFirst();
            readed[i]=c.getInt(0);
            readed[i+1]=c.getInt(1);
            i+=2;
        }

I should use:

  for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++){
   c.moveToNext();
   //readed[i]=c.getInt(0);
   readed[i]=c.getInt(1);
   last=i;
  }

Right now it is saving new rows, incrementing them correctly and reading as I wanted to.
For that, yeah... shame on me.

Comment: Oh, and I have written such a short story on this :-) well, at least you could tell me if my last guess (about hiding a nullpointerexception) was valid :-)

Comment: As I writted in second comment - I hidded this exception because code is meant to create table only one time. You know - when it is without try{}catch{} it is creating table first time so it doesn't give SQLException, but then another time it will. So when it is in try{}catch{} it is also creating table first time, then another time when I run app it doesn't give SQLException, app is working and table is already created :) Or maybe I should somehow check if the table exist, but I think it would be longer to ask database if table exist, put answet in cursor and check it.

Answer (score 0):

you have not used auto increment for your database.? as can be seen in your database

That's the reason you are getting only 1 result.

use drop table and try again

change

```
       for(int i=0;i<readed.length;i++){
```

to

```
      for(int i=0;i<readed[].length;i++){
```

Comment: As in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388459/how-to-make-auto-increment-on-android-sqlite-database following JibW answer the "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" should create automatically incremented row.

Comment: change

       for(int i=0;i<readed.length;i++){

to

      for(int i=0;i<readed[].length;i++){

Answer (score 0):

You can just clear the Application Data, using 'Manage Apps' --> 'Clear Data' (This would delete all the previously created Databases, Preferences and all that stuff). And again execute the code using AUTOINCREMENT.

```
database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE cars(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,data INTEGER);");
```

Comment: It's too long by about 7000 characters for comment :/

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to behave exactly as written.

First you have some code that checks if there is a row in the results. It then proceeds to read the first result, and **only the first result** (maybe you are mistaking `if` for `while`? but in such case you have got `moveToFirst` wrong, even if you switch `if` for a `while` it will only read the first row, again and again) and place it into `readed` array.

Since `readed` contains just the numbers from the first row, the second snippet will loop over the whole array but print only the two first numbers (the values that are not null). And this is exactly the result you report.

Perhaps you wanted to write a code that loads **all** the cursor rows into `readed`? It would be a loop (not a conditional statement):

```
while (c.hasNext()) {
   c.moveToNext();
   readed[i] = c.getInt(0);
   readed[i+1] = c.getInt(1);
   i += 2;
}
```

And swallowing exceptions is an offense and an insult to everyone answering your question.

Tendency towards hiding errors instead of solving them is visible in this line of your code:

```
if(readed[i] != null) {
```

If it wasn't for the former errors, this code would not be necessary. I believe that the first time you run the loop you got a null pointer exception, and instead of checking the logic of filling the array (what is a `null` value doing there?!) you just removed the symptoms. This is just like swallowing an exception: shooting the messenger because you don't like some news.

**EDIT / UPDATE**

As for creating tables, each sqlite database in Android has a version number (a simple int that you can read or write, a fresh database starts with 0), so the low-level way of handling this would be to have something like:

if (database.getVersion == 0) {
    // ...create table here...
    database.setVersion(1);
}

Most people end using Sqliteopenhelper, as it helps a bit in solving other problems (that you have not hit yet, but probably will) like concurrent access to the database.

Comment: For the first part of answer, exactly, I saw it too. Actually I was reading a book and I rewritted that part from the book without thinking. But I found that it is reading only first row... Yeah, I know. Sory for swallowing exceptions, but will checking if table exists be faster/better? Sorry that I'm asking, but I'm not a professional.

Comment: @AdamSt: I don't expect you to be sorry about asking. It's a sort of price you pay on stackoverflow: I answer your question and in return you have to read my pompous preaching (and that makes me feel better about myself) :-). I added a bit of solution for creating tables; and the problem with swallowing solutions is that if anything goes wrong while creating the table - you will never know.