# Android - SQLite AUTOINCREMENT not incrementing primary key

Tags: android, sqlite, auto-increment

I've searched around stack overflow and couldn't find a solution for this. 
This is my onCreate code for SQLite.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE cards (cardID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, question VARCHAR, answer VARCHAR, subject VARCHAR)";
    database.execSQL(query);
}
```

I use this to insert from the adapter (DbTools)

```
public void insertCard(HashMap<String, String> queryValues) {

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("question", queryValues.get("question"));
    values.put("answer", queryValues.get("answer"));
    values.put("subject", queryValues.get("subject"));

    database.insert("cards", null, values);
    database.close();

}
```

This is the way I am inserting data into the database.

```
HashMap<String, String> Values = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
Values.put("question", newQuestion);
Values.put("answer", newAnswer);
Values.put("subject", newSubject);
dbTools.insertCard(Values);
```

Where newQuestion, newAnswer and newSubject are variables that define the user input from an edittext field.

When I check the database by calling a toast, everything is inserted except the cardID which is inserted as Null. 
Doubting my toast check, I downloaded a database viewer and also found that the cardID was null.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Replace `cardID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` to `cardID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE cards (cardID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, question VARCHAR, answer VARCHAR, subject VARCHAR)";
    database.execSQL(query);
}
```

You don't have to specifically write `AUTO_INCREMENT` as in SQLite.

Just have to define the primary key Field as `_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: any reason why not defined AUTO_INCREMENT?

Comment: Still gives null as the result.

Comment: @IrfanMaulana: would u close the database after inserting values?

Comment: @AnilBhatiya Closing doen't help either as I've defined it in db tools. Didn't include that in the code. Edited now.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
integer primary key autoincrement not null
```

Then it will be:

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE cards (cardID integer primary key autoincrement not null, question   VARCHAR, answer VARCHAR, subject VARCHAR)";
```

**EDIT**

Just check my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class AABDatabaseManager
{
Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private final String DB_NAME = "MY_DB";
private final int DB_VERSION = 1;

public AABDatabaseManager(Context context)
{       
            this.context = context;
    CustomSQLiteOpenHelper helper = new CustomSQLiteOpenHelper(context);
    this.db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void addRow(String StringOne, String StringTwo)
{   
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("Username", StringOne);
    values.put("Passwrd", StringTwo);
    try{
              db.insert("My_table", null, values);
            }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class CustomSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    public CustomSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context,DB_NAME,null,DB_VERSION);
    }


    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE My_table(ID integer primary key autoincrement not null, Username text, Passwrd text)";                         ");";       
        db.execSQL(query);
    }
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {

    }
}
```

Insert data like this:

```
AABDatabaseManager db = new AABDatabaseManager(this);
db.addRow(Stringvalue1,Stringvalue2);
```

Comment: Still gives result as null.

Comment: @IrfanMaulana : I edited my answer. Just try that code. It is easy and working fine for me.

Comment: @ShaunzzDroid Thanks, I figured it out. Check out my edited post. :)

Comment: thanks bro it work fine for me..therefore i have voted you :)

Comment: I have a question, would you tell me what is the use of constructor in database class?

Answer (score 0):

I have read (in Android Studio Development Essentials) that Android is picky about the name of the primary key and wants it to always be `_id`.

Also, according to [How to make AUTO_INCREMENT on Android SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388459/how-to-make-auto-increment-on-android-sqlite-database) autoincrement is implied and should be avoided.

Therefore, try using the following:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE cards (_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, question VARCHAR, answer VARCHAR, subject VARCHAR)";
    database.execSQL(query);
}
```